# User object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

I am creating an app in which it manages ranking and ELO functions for a local hobby game store. I am using django to write the application. I am having troubles trying to figure out how to access a user's model from their name.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mtg_currentELO = models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    mtg_highestELO = models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    mtg_lowestELO = models.IntegerField(default=1000)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    
    if request.method == 'GET':

        user1 = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['player1']) 
        user2 = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['player2'])
        print(user1, user2) # DEBUG LINE -- it does find
        print(user1.mtg_currentELO) # DEBUG LINE -- it does NOT FIND
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish is the find `mtg_currentELO` from the user1. However, I can't access it via `user1.mtg_currentELO`. How can I access the property `mtg_currentELO` of a `Profile`, via the user's name?

Comment: Could you please post your User class?

Comment: @Janukasamaranyake , I do not have a user class, is this a flaw?

Comment: Yeah, because profile and User classes should be two different classes with one-to-one unidirectional or bidirectional in order to access profile properties from a user object.

Comment: Use `user_instance.profile.mtg_currentELO`. You will have to handle cases where a user does not have a profile though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign a related name to OneToOneField like this:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="assigned_profile")
    ...
```

then you will be able to access it like `user1.assigned_profile.mtg_currentELO`

You can find details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField